# Pass chain function as paramter as parameter in php

Tags: php, laravel, method-chaining

I have a function. It has method chaining that needs to be performed.

```
public function someFunction()
{
        $query=$this->model;
    $query->select($columns)
        ->skip($request->get('start') * $request->get('length'))
        ->take($request->get('length'))
        ->orderBy(
            $request->get('sort_column'),
            $request->get('sort_direction')
        )
        ->get();

    //Some other task      
}
```

It was working fine but I need a slight modification in that function what I want is I want to pass a join in that function for method chaining.

```
public function someFunction($join_as_parameter)
{
        $query=$this->model;
    $query->select($columns)
        //Join should be executed here as a parameter in method chaning . 
        ->skip($request->get('start') * $request->get('length'))
        ->take($request->get('length'))
        ->orderBy(
            $request->get('sort_column'),
            $request->get('sort_direction')
        )
        ->get();

    //Some other task      
}
```

So that final function execution will be like this

```
public function someFunction($join_as_parameter)
{
        $query=$this->model;
    $query->select($columns)
        ->join('table','sometable.id', '=', 'other_table') 
        ->skip($request->get('start') * $request->get('length'))
        ->take($request->get('length'))
        ->orderBy(
             $request->get('sort_column'),
             $request->get('sort_direction')
        )
        ->get();

    //Some other task      
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `$join_as_parameter`? is it a table name?

Comment: Ii updated the question

Comment: you have already answered your question

Comment: is `$join_as_parameter` is set of prams as `'table', 'sometable.id', '=', 'other_table'` or the whole `join('table','sometable.id', '=', 'other_table')` functions ?

Comment: Or you can explain the use case and someone can provide a better solution.

Comment: Whole part of the join

Comment: Why not pass all the params and make the join inside `someFunction` ?

Comment: What if I want multiple join then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can achieve what you need.

```
use DB;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause;

public function someFunction(Closure $join_clauser)
{
    //create Query Builder object
    $query = DB::query();

    //Add the `$join` object to the table joins for this query
    $join_as_parameter = call_user_func($join_closure, $query);
    $query->joins = array_merge((array) $query->joins, [$join_as_parameter]);

    $query->select($columns)
        ->skip($request->get('start') * $request->get('length'))
        ->take($request->get('length'))
        ->orderBy(
            $request->get('sort_column'),
            $request->get('sort_direction')
        )
        ->get();

    //Some other task
}

//create Query Builder object
$query = DB::query();
```

And execute the functions as,

```
someFunction(function($query){
    // return JoinClause object with joining conditions
    return (new JoinClause($query, 'inner', 'table'))
            ->on('table.id', '=', 'othe_table.table_id');
});
```

Furthermore, you can modify this to pass array of `joins` to add multiple `joins` your the query.

To use this with eloquent models, replace

```
$query = DB::query();
```

with

```
$query = Model::query()->getQuery();
```

**NOTE** : `->getQuery()` is used to retrieve the `Query\Builder` object since `JoinClause` expects it as the first param.

Comment: Can't this be achieved using Model instead of DB::query()

Comment: Yes. Can pass eloquent builder as well

Comment: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Model\Product::$joins has no effect

Comment: I updated the answer with the **Eloquent** way. But, I don't get the error. What's your Laravel & PHP version ?

Comment: Never mind. Updated the answer. replace `$query->joins[] = $join;` with `$query->joins = array_merge((array) $query->joins, [$join_as_parameter]);`

Comment: I have updated the function a bit . The thing is I get $query from the $this->model . Do I need to pass another query also

Comment: But the join part didn't get executed in the sql query

Comment: May be you are using different query objects.

Comment: One question. Do I need to pass the builder . I have already retirived the query without passing the Builder

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned that in the answer. `JoinClause` needs the query builder you are using as it's first param.

Comment: So you need to use that without passing it from outside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184084/discussion-between-ashok-poudel-and-ijas-ameenudeen).